# Bootstrap 3.3.7 hidden-lg-up not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to design a a mobile version of a game I've been working on. Apologies for the messy code, it's nothing serious. I've decided to use a hamburger-menu for the mobile version and want to hide it on desktop devices. For this I found "hidden-lg-up" in the bootstrap documentation but it doesn't seem to be working. I at least know that the bootstrap js is loaded because if I change the name I get an error in the browser console.

The element I'm trying this with is the "hamburger-menu-toggle" and "hamburger-menu".

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CEO Panel</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png?v=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <!-- JQUERY -->
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-ui-1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- LIBS AND PLUGINS -->
    <script src="js/libs/jquery-mousewheel-3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/mapbox.js/jquery.mapbox.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/countdown/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>

    <!-- GAME JS -->
    <script src="js/game_logic/main.js"></script>
    <script src="js/game_logic/buttons.js"></script>

    <script src="js/libs/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div id="map-wrapper">
        <img id="map" src="res/los_santos_map.png" alt="Los Santos Map">
        <div id="map-content">
          <!--<div class="map-marker owned" id="warehouse1"></div>
          <div class="map-marker for-sale" id="warehouse2"></div>-->

          <?php
            $pdo = pdo();
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];

            foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM warehouses") as $row){
              $warehouse_id = $row['id'];
              $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM warehouse_contracts WHERE warehouse_id LIKE '$warehouse_id' AND username LIKE '$username'");
              $statement->execute();
              $rowCount = $statement->rowCount();

              //find out the size of the warehouse
              if($row['slots'] < 64){
                $size = "small";
              }
              else if($row['slots'] >= 64 && $row['slots'] < 256){
                $size = "medium";
              }
              else{
                $size = "large";
              }

              //find out if it's owned by the user
              if($rowCount>0){
                echo '<div class="map-marker owned ' . $size . '" id="warehouse' . $row['id'] . '" style="top: ' . $row['y'] . 'px; left: ' . $row['x'] . 'px;"></div>';
              }
              else{
                echo '<div class="map-marker for-sale ' . $size . '" id="warehouse' . $row['id'] . '" style="top: ' . $row['y'] . 'px; left: ' . $row['x'] . 'px;"></div>';
              }
            }
          ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div style="background-image: url('res/radar-overlay.png'); width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; background-size: cover; opacity: 0.2; pointer-events: none;"></div>

      <div id="HUD">
        <div id="hamburger-menu-toggle" class="hidden-lg-up">
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
          <div></div>
        </div>
        <div id="hamburger-menu" class="hidden-lg-up">

        </div>

        <a href="index.php?page=logout"><div id="logout" class="button">LOGOUT</div></a>

        <?php
          if(isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] === "TRUE"){
            echo '
              <div id="admin-stats">
                <h1>map.x: <span id="map_x"></span><br>map.y: <span id="map_y"></span></h1>
                <h1>map.height: <span id="map_height"></span><br>map.width: <span id="map_width"></span><br>mouse.x: <span id="mouse_x"></span><br>mouse.y: <span id="mouse_y"></span></h1>
              </div>
            ';
          }
        ?>

        <h1 id="cash">
          <?php
            $pdo = pdo();
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE username LIKE '$username'");
            $statement->execute();
            $results = $statement->fetch();

            echo '$' . number_format($results['cash']);
          ?>
        </h1>

        <div id="warehouse-toggle">
          <div class="button toggle-selected">ALL</div>
          <div class="button toggle">OWNED</div>
          <div class="button toggle">SMALL</div>
          <div class="button toggle">MEDIUM</div>
          <div class="button toggle">LARGE</div>
        </div>

        <div id="stock-actions">
          <?php
            $pdo = pdo();
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM shipments WHERE status LIKE 'active' AND username LIKE ?");
            $statement->bindParam(1, $username);
            $statement->execute();
            $row_count = $statement->rowCount();

            if($row_count == 0){
              echo '
                <div id="buy-stock-button" class="button">BUY</div>
              ';

              $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM storage WHERE username LIKE ?");
              $statement->bindParam(1, $username);
              $statement->execute();
              $row_count = $statement->rowCount();
              if($row_count > 0){
                echo '
                  <div id="sell-stock-button" class="button">SELL</div>
                ';
              }
              else{
                echo '
                  <div id="sell-stock-button" class="button disabled">SELL</div>
                ';
              }
            }
            else{
              echo '
                <div id="buy-stock-button" class="button disabled">BUY</div>
                <div id="sell-stock-button" class="button disabled">SELL</div>
              ';
            }
          ?>
          <div id="upgrades-button" class="button">UPGRADES</div>
        </div>

        <div id="page-toggle">
          <div class="button toggle">SUMMARY PAGE</div>
          <div class="button toggle-selected">WAREHOUSE MAP</div>
        </div>

        <div class="dialog" id="owned-warehouse-dialog">
          <div class="close-button">x</div>
        </div>

        <div class="dialog" id="buy-warehouse-dialog">
          <div class="close-button">x</div>

          <?php
            /*
            $pdo = pdo();
            $warehouse_id = $_GET['warehouse_id'];
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM warehouses WHERE id LIKE ?");
            $statement->bindParam(1, $warehouse_id);
            $statement->execute();
            $warehouse = $statement->fetch();

            echo '
              <h1>WAREHOUSE ' . $warehouse_id . '</h1>
              <p>STATUS:<span class="right-text">FOR SALE</span></p>
              <p>WAREHOUSE SLOTS:<span class="right-text">' . $warehouse['slots'] . '</span></p>
              <p>COST:<span class="right-text">' . $warehouse['price'] . '</span></p>

              <div class="submit-button">BUY</div>
            ';
            */
          ?>
        </div>

        <div class="dialog" id="buy-warehouse-dialog"></div>

        <div class="dialog" id="buy-stock-dialog">
          <div class="close-button">x</div>

          <form action="index.php?action=buy_crates" method="post">
            <h1>BUY CARGO CRATES</h1>
            <p>TYPE</p>
            <div class="selection-list">
              <?php
                $pdo = pdo();
                foreach($pdo->query("SELECT * FROM crate_types") as $row){
                  echo '<div class="button toggle">' . strtoupper($row['name']) . '</div>';
                }
              ?>
              <input class="hidden" name="type" type="text" required>
            </div>
            <p>QUANTITY</p>
            <div class="selection-list">

              <?php
                $pdo = pdo();
                $username = $_SESSION['username'];

                $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(slots) FROM warehouses INNER JOIN warehouse_contracts ON warehouses.id=warehouse_contracts.warehouse_id WHERE username LIKE '$username'");
                $statement->execute();
                $slots = $statement->fetch();

                $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM storage WHERE username LIKE ?");
                $statement->bindParam(1, $username);
                $statement->execute();
                $crates = $statement->fetch();

                $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM transport_upgrades WHERE username LIKE ? AND type LIKE 'storage'");
                $statement->bindParam(1, $username);
                $statement->execute();
                $storage_upgrades = $statement->rowCount() + 1;

                $available_slots = $slots['SUM(slots)'] - $crates['SUM(quantity)'];

                if($available_slots >= 1 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades)){
                  echo '<div class="button toggle">' . 1 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }
                else{
                  echo '<div class="disabled">' . 1 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }

                if($available_slots >= 2 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades)){
                  echo '<div class="button toggle">' . 2 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }
                else{
                  echo '<div class="disabled">' . 2 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }

                if($available_slots >= 4 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades)){
                  echo '<div class="button toggle">' . 4 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }
                else{
                  echo '<div class="disabled">' . 4 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }

                if($available_slots >= 8 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades)){
                  echo '<div class="button toggle">' . 8 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }
                else{
                  echo '<div class="disabled">' . 8 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }

                if($available_slots >= 16 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades)){
                  echo '<div class="button toggle">' . 16 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }
                else{
                  echo '<div class="disabled">' . 16 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }

                if($available_slots >= 32 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades)){
                  echo '<div class="button toggle">' . 32 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }
                else{
                  echo '<div class="disabled">' . 32 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades) . '</div>';
                }

                if($available_slots < 1 * pow(2, $storage_upgrades)){
                  echo '
                    <input class="hidden" name="quantity" type="text" required>
                  </div>
                  <p>RISK:<span class="right-text" id="delivery-risk">0%</span></p>
                  <p>PROFIT MARGIN:<span class="right-text" id="delivery-profit">0%</span></p>
                  <p>PRICE:<span class="right-text" id="delivery-price">$0</span></p>
                  <input class="submit-button disabled" type="submit" value="BUY">
                ';
                }
                else{
                  echo '
                    <input class="hidden" name="quantity" type="text" required>
                  </div>
                  <p>RISK:<span class="right-text" id="delivery-risk">0%</span></p>
                  <p>PROFIT MARGIN:<span class="right-text" id="delivery-profit">0%</span></p>
                  <p>PRICE:<span class="right-text" id="delivery-price">$0</span></p>
                  <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="BUY">
                ';
                }
              ?>


          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="dialog" id="sell-stock-dialog">
          <div class="close-button">x</div>
          <?php
            $pdo = pdo();
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM((price*((profit/100)+1))*quantity), SUM(price*quantity), SUM(quantity), AVG(profit) FROM storage INNER JOIN crate_types ON storage.crate_type_id=crate_types.id WHERE username LIKE ?");
            $statement->bindParam(1, $username);
            $statement->execute();
            $rows = $statement->fetch();
            $quantity = $rows['SUM(quantity)'];
            $value = round($rows['SUM((price*((profit/100)+1))*quantity)'], 0);
            $original_cost = round($rows['SUM(price*quantity)'], 0);
            $profit_margin = round($rows['AVG(profit)'], 0);

            echo '
                <h1>SELL CARGO CRATES</h1>
                <p>CRATES: <span class="right-text">' . $quantity . '</span></p>
                <p>RISK: <span class="right-text"></span></p>
                <p>PROFIT MARGIN: <span class="right-text">' . $profit_margin . '%</span></p>
                <p>ORIGINAL COST: <span class="right-text">$' . number_format($original_cost) .'</span></p>
                <p>PROFIT: <span class="right-text">$' . number_format($value - $original_cost) . '</span></p>
                <p>TOTAL VALUE: <span class="right-text">$' . number_format($value) .'</span></p>
                <a href="index.php?action=sell_crates"><div class="submit-button">SELL</div></a>
            ';
          ?>
        </div>

        <?php
          $pdo = pdo();
          $username = $_SESSION['username'];
          $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM shipments WHERE username LIKE '$username' AND status LIKE 'active' LIMIT 1");
          $statement->execute();
          $row_count = $statement->rowCount();
          $row1 = $statement->fetch();

          $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM shipments INNER JOIN crate_types ON shipments.crate_type_id=crate_types.id WHERE username LIKE '$username' AND status LIKE 'active' LIMIT 1");
          $statement->execute();
          $row2 = $statement->fetch();

          if($row_count > 0){
            echo '<div id="active-shipment">';
            if($row1['type'] === "purchase"){
              echo '
                <h1 id="countdown"></h1>
                <p>Incoming shipment of ' . $row2['quantity'] . ' crates of ' . $row2['name'] . '</p>
              ';
            }
            else if($row1['type'] === "sale"){
              echo '
                <h1 id="countdown"></h1>
                <p>Outgoing shipment of ' . $row1['quantity'] . ' crates with a value of $' . number_format($row1['value']) . '</p>
              ';
            }
            echo '
              </div>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  $("#countdown").countdown("' . $row1['arrival'] . '", function(event) {
                    var arrival = {
                      days: event.strftime("%D"),
                      hours: event.strftime("%H"),
                      minutes: event.strftime("%M"),
                      seconds: event.strftime("%Ss")
                    };

                    if(arrival.days <= 0){
                      arrival.days = "";
                    }
                    else{
                      arrival.days += "d";
                    }

                    if(arrival.hours <= 0){
                      arrival.hours = "";
                    }
                    else{
                      arrival.hours += "h";
                    }

                    if(arrival.minutes <= 0){
                      arrival.minutes = "";
                    }
                    else{
                      arrival.minutes += "m";
                    }

                      $(this).text(arrival.days + " " + arrival.hours + " " + arrival.minutes + " " + arrival.seconds);

                    if(new Date("' . $row1['arrival'] . '") <= new Date()){
                      window.location.replace("index.php");
                    }
                    });

                  $("title").countdown("' . $row1['arrival'] . '", function(event){
                    var arrival = {
                      days: event.strftime("%D"),
                      hours: event.strftime("%H"),
                      minutes: event.strftime("%M"),
                      seconds: event.strftime("%Ss")
                    };

                    if(arrival.days <= 0){
                      arrival.days = "";
                    }
                    else{
                      arrival.days += "d";
                    }

                    if(arrival.hours <= 0){
                      arrival.hours = "";
                    }
                    else{
                      arrival.hours += "h";
                    }

                    if(arrival.minutes <= 0){
                      arrival.minutes = "";
                    }
                    else{
                      arrival.minutes += "m";
                    }

                    $(this).text(arrival.days + " " + arrival.hours + " " + arrival.minutes + " " + arrival.seconds + " - CEO Panel");
                    });
              </script>
            ';
          }
        ?>

        <div class="dialog" id="upgrades-dialog">
          <div class="close-button">x</div>
          <h1>UPGRADES</h1>

          <p>TRANSPORT TRUCKS</p>
          <p style="font-size: 16px;">These trucks are used for <strong>purchases</strong>.</p>
          <?php
            $upgrade_cost = calculate_upgrade_cost("trucks", "speed");

            $pdo = pdo();
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?");
            $statement->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['username']);
            $statement->execute();
            $user = $statement->fetch();

            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM transport_upgrades WHERE vehicle LIKE 'trucks' AND username LIKE ? AND type LIKE 'speed'");
            $statement->bindParam(1, $username);
            $statement->execute();
            $previous_upgrades = $statement->rowCount();

            $crate_delivery_time = explode('.', 1 * (3 * (1 - ($previous_upgrades * 0.03))));

            if(strpos((string)$crate_delivery_time[0], "-") !== false){
              $crate_delivery_time[0] = 0;
              $crate_delivery_time[1] = 0;
            }

            if(($crate_delivery_time[0] <= 0 && $crate_delivery_time[1] <= 0) || $crate_delivery_time[0] < 0){
              echo '
                <div class="upgrade">
                  <p>SPEED</p><div class="upgrade-button-disabled">UPGRADE</div>
                  <div class="upgrade-cost">Limit for upgrades reached.</div>
                </div>
              ';
            }
            else if($user['cash'] < $upgrade_cost){
              echo '
                <div class="upgrade">
                  <p>SPEED</p><div class="upgrade-button-disabled">UPGRADE</div>
                  <div class="upgrade-cost">COST <span class="right-text red-text">$' . number_format($upgrade_cost) . '</span></div>
                </div>
              ';
            }
            else if($user['cash'] >= $upgrade_cost){
              echo '
                <div class="upgrade">
                  <p>SPEED</p><a href="index.php?action=upgrade&vehicle=trucks&type=speed"><div class="upgrade-button">UPGRADE</div></a>
                  <div class="upgrade-cost">COST <span class="right-text">$' . number_format($upgrade_cost) . '</span></div>
                </div>
              ';
            }

            $upgrade_cost = calculate_upgrade_cost("trucks", "storage");

            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?");
            $statement->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['username']);
            $statement->execute();
            $user = $statement->fetch();

            if($user['cash'] >= $upgrade_cost){
              echo '
                <div class="upgrade">
                  <p>STORAGE</p><a href="index.php?action=upgrade&vehicle=trucks&type=storage"><div class="upgrade-button">UPGRADE</div></a>
                  <div class="upgrade-cost">COST <span class="right-text">$' . number_format($upgrade_cost) . '</span></div>
                </div>
              ';
            }
            else{
              echo '
                <div class="upgrade">
                  <p>STORAGE</p><div class="upgrade-button-disabled">UPGRADE</div>
                  <div class="upgrade-cost">COST <span class="right-text red-text">$' . number_format($upgrade_cost) . '</span></div>
                </div>
              ';
            }
          ?>
          <!--
          <div class="upgrade">
            <p>STORAGE</p><a href="index.php?action=upgrade&vehicle=trucks&type=storage"><div class="upgrade-button">UPGRADE</div></a>
          </div>
          -->

          <br>
          <p>TRANSPORT PLANES</p>
          <p style="font-size: 16px;">These planes are used for <strong>sales</strong>.</p>
          <?php
            $upgrade_cost = calculate_upgrade_cost("planes", "speed");

            $pdo = pdo();
            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE username LIKE ?");
            $statement->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['username']);
            $statement->execute();
            $user = $statement->fetch();

            $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM transport_upgrades WHERE vehicle LIKE 'planes' AND username LIKE ? AND type LIKE 'speed'");
            $statement->bindParam(1, $username);
            $statement->execute();
            $previous_upgrades = $statement->rowCount();

            $crate_delivery_time = explode('.', 1 * (3 * (1 - ($previous_upgrades * 0.03))));

            if(strpos((string)$crate_delivery_time[0], "-") !== false){
              $crate_delivery_time[0] = 0;
              $crate_delivery_time[1] = 0;
            }

            if(($crate_delivery_time[0] <= 0 && $crate_delivery_time[1] <= 0) || $crate_delivery_time[0] < 0){
              echo '
                <div class="upgrade">
                  <p>SPEED</p><div class="upgrade-button-disabled">UPGRADE</div>
                  <div class="upgrade-cost">Limit for upgrades reached.</div>
                </div>
              ';
            }
            else if($user['cash'] < $upgrade_cost){
              echo '
                <div class="upgrade">
                  <p>SPEED</p><div class="upgrade-button-disabled">UPGRADE</div>
                  <div class="upgrade-cost">COST <span class="right-text red-text">$' . number_format($upgrade_cost) . '</span></div>
                </div>
              ';
            }
            else if($user['cash'] >= $upgrade_cost){
              echo '
                <div class="upgrade">
                  <p>SPEED</p><a href="index.php?action=upgrade&vehicle=planes&type=speed"><div class="upgrade-button">UPGRADE</div></a>
                  <div class="upgrade-cost">COST <span class="right-text">$' . number_format($upgrade_cost) . '</span></div>
                </div>
              ';
            }
          ?>
        </div>

        <div id="warehouse-space">
          <div id="used-space"></div>
          <p>Used warehouse space:
            <?php
              $pdo = pdo();
              $username = $_SESSION['username'];
              $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(slots) FROM warehouses INNER JOIN warehouse_contracts ON warehouses.id=warehouse_contracts.warehouse_id WHERE username LIKE '$username'");
              $statement->execute();
              $row = $statement->fetch();
              $slots = $row['SUM(slots)'];

              $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM storage WHERE username LIKE '$username'");
              $statement->execute();
              $row = $statement->fetch();
              $crates = $row['SUM(quantity)'];

              if($crates === 0 || !isset($crates)){
                $crates = 0;
              }

              $percentage_used = round(($crates/$slots)*100, 1);

              echo $crates . '/' . $slots . ' (' . $percentage_used . '%)';
            ?>
          </p>
            <?php
              echo '
                <script>
                  $("#used-space").css("width", ' . $percentage_used . ' + "%");
                </script>
              ';
            ?>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="summary"></div>

      <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['random_event']) && $_SESSION['random_event']['recent'] === true){
          $robbers = array(
            "Hell's Angels",
            "The Lost",
            "some asian streetpunks",
            "a pair of irish virgins",
            "the russian mob",
            "some methheads",
            "a korean crew"
          );

          if($_SESSION['random_event']['shipment_type'] === "purchase"){
            echo '
              <div class="alert-background"></div>
              <div class="alert">
                <img class="companion-speech" src="res/companion-speeches/random-event.png">
                <h1>Oh no!</h1>
                <p>Boss, I\'ve got some bad news. Your recent shipment of <strong>' . $_SESSION['random_event']['ordered_quantity'] . '</strong> crates was hijacked during transport by ' . $robbers[rand(0, count($robbers) - 1)] . '. They managed to get away with <strong>' . $_SESSION['random_event']['random_event_penalty'] . '</strong> crates. Though, your crew did kill <strong>' . rand(1, 20) . '</strong> of them before they took off with the product.</p>
                <div class="ok-button">OK</div>
              </div>
            ';
          }
          unset($_SESSION['random_event']);
        }
      ?>
    </main>
    <div id="loading">
      <p>Loading, please wait..</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bootstrap 3.x, you'll want to use `class = "hidden-md hidden-lg"` to hide content on desktops (screen resolutions `>= 992 pixels`).

```
<div id="HUD">
    <div id="hamburger-menu-toggle" class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
    <div id="hamburger-menu" class="hidden-md hidden-lg">

    </div>
```

Bootstrap 4 is in alpha still, so I wouldn't recommend using it yet, aside from for testing purposes.

Also, make sure you put this in your `head` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
```

Comment: I've just tried this, it doesn't work! I get no errors. It simply doesn't comply.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're including the Bootstrap CSS in your page. You're only loading the JS.

Comment: I tried this before making the OP but this doesn't help. It simply redesigns some of my buttons etc. I've just tried it again to be sure but no changes except for the change to design (which I don't want).

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. If the Bootstrap CSS is not loaded, you will not be able to utilize the `hidden-*` classes.

Comment: I see, now it works! So my mistake was not including the css. Although, the bootstrap css does some unpleasant things to the buttons.

without css: http://i.imgur.com/13UPM1m.jpg
with css: http://i.imgur.com/2x9vmxd.jpg

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem. As for the buttons (in your case it looks like `div.button`), you can override that in your own CSS to fix those issues. Put your `main.css` after Bootstrap's CSS in `head`.

Comment: Keep playing around with the styles - you'll get it. Bootstrap doesn't define `div.button`, only the `.btn` and `.btn-*` classes, so it's probably a difference in the padding of the `div` elements.

Answer (score 0):

this feature is a new feature in the new version of bootstrap v4 but you are using bootstrap 3, you can use `.hidden-md` and `.hidden-lg` instead.

[Bootstrap Doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

[image]

Comment: I see. I didn't find anything about that in the documentation though. Do you know if there is something similar in v.3? I simply want to hide a specific element on desktop devices.

Comment: Updated again, with screen shot

Comment: Well, so here's the deal. I tried the same code again but with bootstrap v.4, with the same result. Even trying what you just recommended doesn't work..

I just tried this: "visible-xs-block visible-sm-block hidden-lg hidden-xl"

Comment: Sorry i had it mixed up you need to use hidden classes not visible, I've updated my answer and please see to the screen shot

Comment: Thanks for the help! Though my error was not including the bootstrap css.

Comment: These `hidden` and `visible` plus `.hidden-*-up` and `.hidden-*-down` have all been removed in Bootstrap 4.0 beta

Answer (score 0):

You can skip using bootstrap CSS, and use jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($(window).width() <= 997) {
    $('p').hide();
  }
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 997) {
      $('#hamburger-menu-toggle').hide();
    } else {
      $('#hamburger-menu-toggle').show();
    }
  });
});
```